# What does $$ and <generated> mean in Java stacktrace?

Tags: java, spring, stack-trace, cglib

I often get stacktraces like this one (please see the arrow for the confusing line):

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:164)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:741)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:589)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
--------->      at com.panpwr.admin.services.detector.SimpleDetectorPersistenceService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66303639.saveComplexRuleAndActionTemplates(<generated>)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
...
...
...
```

What does the `$$` sign mean, and what is the 'generated' in this line?
`com.panpwr.admin.services.detector.SimpleDetectorPersistenceService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66303639.saveComplexRuleAndActionTemplates(<generated>)`

And why does it only say the executed method but not the line number in it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`$` is an allowed character in class names.

The name `SimpleDetectorPersistenceService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66303639` hints that it is a class which was dynamically generated at runtime by Spring framework using CGLIB.

They use `$$` and a numeric offset to make this class name unique to avoid conflicts with existing classes.

The string `(<generated>)` in the stracktrace too was generated by [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib):
When CGLIB creates a class at runtime it uses `<generated>` as placeholder for the name of the source file. The stacktrace then simply prints this string instead of the real source file and line number.